# Tensorflow 2 LSTM model doesn't learn using a Sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm currently using a LSTM model to make timeserie predictions with Tensorflow 2.2.0

I've been using a large dataset and everything works nicely.
However, the dataset creation takes a lot of RAM and I wanted to use a `tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence` to solve the issue, my problem is the following:

**When using a Sequence, my model doesn't learn anymore (it predicts the average of the real signal over the whole dataset)**

My dataset is created from two python lists `x_train_flights` and `y_train_flights`, each containing pandas `DataFrame`s. For each `(x_train_flight, y_train_flight)` of this list:

- `x_train_flight` of shape `(-1, features)` containing `features` signals
- `y_train_flight` of shape `(-1, 1)` containing one signal being aligned in time with the ones from `x_train_flights`

The system looks like as follow (I am not allowed to share the real data, I've recreated the graph using pseudo-random signals instead):

[image: exemple of prediction]

Here, `features=2` (the blue and orange lines), and `look_back=5`. That is to say, the 10 points (from `x_train_flights`) in the rectangle are used to predict the golden point (which is compared to the corresponding point in `y_train_flights` during the training phase). The gray points are previous predictions.

To create my dataset, I've been using these functions:

```py
def lstm_shapify(sequence, look_back, features):
    res = np.empty((look_back, len(sequence), features), dtype=np.float32)

    for i in range(look_back):
        res[i] = np.roll(sequence, -i * features)

    return np.transpose(res, axes=(1, 0, 2))[:-look_back + 1]


def make_dataset(x_flights, y_flights, look_back, features):
    x = np.empty((0, look_back, features), dtype=np.float32)
    y = np.empty((0, 1), dtype=np.float32)

    for i in range(len(x_flights)):
        x_sample = x_flights[i].values
        y_sample = y_flights[i].values[look_back - 1:]

        x = np.concatenate([x, lstm_shapify(x_sample, look_back, features)])
        y = np.concatenate([y, y_sample])

    return x, y
```

And I fit my network with the following:

```py
model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    epochs=7,
    batch_size=batch_size
)
```

So, I've created this custom Sequence:

```py
class LSTMGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(
            self,
            x_flights: List[DataFrame],
            y_flights: List[DataFrame],
            look_back: int,
            batch_size: int,
            features: int
    ):
        self.x_flights = x_flights
        self.y_flights = []
        self.look_back = look_back
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.features = features
        self.length = 0

        for y_flight in y_flights:
            y = y_flight.iloc[look_back - 1:].to_numpy()
            self.y_flights.append(y)
            self.length += len(y) // batch_size

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        flight_index = 0

        while True:
            n = len(self.y_flights[flight_index]) // self.batch_size
            if index < n:
                break
            flight_index += 1
            index = index - n

        start_index = index * self.batch_size
        x_batch = lstm_shapify(
            self.x_flights[flight_index]
                .iloc[start_index:start_index + self.batch_size + self.look_back - 1]
                .to_numpy(),
            self.look_back,
            self.features
        )
        y_batch = self.y_flights[flight_index][start_index:start_index + self.batch_size]

        return x_batch, y_batch

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length
```

Each tuple (`x`, `y`) it returns are two numpy arrays of shape `(batch_size, look_back, features)` and `(batch_size, 1)` respectively.

And now I'm trying to fit it with:

```py
model.fit(
    LSTMGenerator(x_train_flights, y_train_flights, look_back, batch_size, features),
    epochs=epochs
)
```

Here is my model:

```py
model = Sequential()    

model.add(LSTM(
    100,
    input_shape=(look_back, features),
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-3),
    bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4)
))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Hope you can help me

EDIT: more details about the datasets

Comment: What types are `x_flights` and `y_flights`? It would be easier if you first converted them to numpy arrays. And can you explain the shapes of your training data?

Comment: Those are pandas `DataFrame`s, I've added hints to my question and the shapes returned by the generator. `y_flights` is converted in the constructor and `x_flights` is converted on the go in the `__getitem__` method.

Comment: Can you show some examples of what data the arrays contains? It's hard to see how x_flights and y_flights are supposed to be related to each other.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist I've edited the question, please let me know if something is still unclear

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist please note that I made a mistake earlier, `x_train_flights` and `y_train_flights` are python lists containing pandas `DataFrames`, I've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by taking a break and looking at the code once again (and I realized it was a silly mistake): the issue of my `Sequence` comes from the samples in each batch being consecutive samples in time, whereas my compute-everything-dataset's batches where nicely shuffled.

My `Sequence` was problematic because the batches were selected at a random index from a random dataset. Now I select each sample at a random index from a random dataset to create a single batch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```
from tensorflow.keras import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.utils import *
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(1234)
tf.random.set_seed(1234)

features = 3
lookback = 7

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(500, input_shape = (lookback, features)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))

XS = np.random.randn(200, features)
YS = np.random.randn(200)

class LookbackSeq(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, XS, YS, batch_size, lookback):
        self.XS = XS
        self.YS = YS
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.lookback = lookback

    def __len__(self):
        n_windows = self.XS.shape[0] - self.lookback
        return int(np.ceil(n_windows / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        base = i * self.batch_size

        n_windows = self.XS.shape[0] - self.lookback
        batch_size = min(n_windows - base, self.batch_size)

        X = np.zeros((batch_size, self.lookback, self.XS.shape[1]))
        Y = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))
        for i in range(batch_size):
            for j in range(self.lookback):
                X[i, j] = self.XS[base + i + j]
            Y[i] = self.YS[base + i + self.lookback]
        return X, Y

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# ALL SAMPLES IN MEMORY
X, Y = [], []
for i in range(len(XS) - lookback):
    X.append(XS[i:i+lookback])
    Y.append(YS[i+lookback])
X, Y = np.array(X), np.array(Y)
model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 10, batch_size = 4, shuffle = False)

# GENERATED ON THE FLY
# gen = LookbackSeq(XS, YS, 4, lookback)
# model.fit(x = gen,
#           steps_per_epoch = len(gen),
#           shuffle = False,
#           epochs = 10)
```

I'm assuming your input data has the shape `X = (n_points, n_features)` and `Y = (n_points,)`. `LookbackSeq` does the batching and windowing (lookback) for you.

You can comment and uncomment the relevant lines to either train with samples generated on the fly or with them all stored in memory. You should get identical results.

Comment: Your `LookbackSeq` works but suffers from the same issue my `LSTMGenerator` has, that is to say my model doesn't learn when using it

Comment: I've updated my answer with code to compare the sequence approach with keeping all samples in memory. On my computer I get identical results which proves that `LookbackSeq` is correct. Your problem therefore lies somewhere else. Possibly in your handling of the pandas DataFrames.

Comment: You're using random data so we can't really know if it performs the same. Either way, I need to use multiple dataframes (or numpy arrays ; handled by the lists of dataframes `x_flights` and `y_flights`) as I can't just concatenate all their samples in a big numpy array for continuity reasons

Comment: I'm setting the seed so that the same data is used whether I use the `LookbackSeq` or not. Since I'm getting the same result there is no error in the code. Therefore your problem must be in some other part of your code. As I suggested before, rework your code so that it only uses plain numpy arrays and not Pandas dataframes. That is very likely to be the root of your problem.

Comment: Btw, when checking whether your model learns, use the model I defined. The model you have with regularization, dropout and BN makes measurements harder.